# Retrieving last record in each group from database with order by

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

There is a table `ticket` that contains data as shown below:

```
Id   Impact   group        create_date
------------------------------------------
1     3        ABC       2020-07-28 00:42:00.0
1     2        ABC       2020-07-28 00:45:00.0
1     3        ABC       2020-07-28 00:48:00.0
1     3        ABC       2020-07-28 00:52:00.0
1     3        XYZ       2020-07-28 00:55:00.0
1     3        XYZ       2020-07-28 00:59:00.0
```

Expected result:

```
Id   Impact   group        create_date
------------------------------------------
1     3        ABC       2020-07-28 00:42:00.0
1     2        ABC       2020-07-28 00:45:00.0
1     3        ABC       2020-07-28 00:52:00.0
1     3        XYZ       2020-07-28 00:59:00.0
```

At present, this is the query that I use:

```
WITH final AS (
    SELECT p.*, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY p.id,p.group,p.impact
                                 ORDER BY p.create_date desc, p.impact) AS rk
      FROM ticket p 
)
SELECT f.*
  FROM final f 
 WHERE f.rk = 1
```

Result, i am getting is:

```
Id   Impact    group         create_date
-----------------------------------------
1     2        ABC       2020-07-28 00:45:00.0
1     3        ABC       2020-07-28 00:52:00.0
1     3        XYZ       2020-07-28 00:59:00.0
```

it seems that partition by is getting precedence over order by values. is there other way to achieve expected result. I am running these queries on amazon Redshift.

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using,

Comment: You need to explain the problem better. The best I can tell, you are looking to "group" (or "partition") by `id` and `group`; then order by date, and select the last row from each sequence of rows with the same `impact`. Correct? Note that `group` is a reserved keyword, which can't be a column name.

Comment: @mathguy your understanding is correct. apologies for leaving the ambiguity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `LEAD()` to check if the `Impact` changes between rows, taking only the rows where the value will change.

```
WITH
  look_forward AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    LEAD(impact) OVER (PARTITION BY id, group ORDER BY create_date) AS lead_impact
  FROM
    ticket
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  look_forward 
WHERE
     lead_impact IS NULL
  OR lead_impact <> impact
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want rows where `id`/`impact`/`group` change relative to the *next* row.  A simple way is to look at the next `create_date` overall and the next `create_date` for the group.  If these are the same, then filter:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(create_date) over (order by create_date) as next_create_date,
             lead(create_date) over (partition by id, impact, group order by create_date) as next_create_date_img
      from ticket t
     ) t
where next_create_date_img is null or next_create_date_img <> next_create_date;
```